# OOP Login/Register

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Im new with PHP and im doing the OOP Login/Registers tutorials for a minor course so it not for a website that ill put on the www. And after an hour or 15 im stuck on a piece of code that doesn't seem to work. I've tried to solve it with a friend of mine who has more knowledge of PHP and I searched google, checked multiple forums and all the YouTube comments for a solution but im stuck. I know all the other code is correct because it all worked fine up to this:

so my qeustion is: what is the correct PHP code to make the unique case work.

```
            case 'unique'     
                $check =$this->_db->get($rule_value,array($item,"=",
                $value));  
    line 40>    if($check->count()){ 
                $this->addError("{$item} bestaat al.");

                with this error:
```

! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a                   non-object in C:\wamp\www\websitegroop\classes\validate.php on line 40 Call Stack

validate class:

```
class Validate  {
private $_passed = false,
        $_errors = array(),
        $_db = null;
public function __construct() {
    $this->_db = Database::getInstance();
}

public function check($source, $items = array()) {
    foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
        foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {

            $value = trim($source[$item]);



            if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)) {
                $this->addError("{$item} is required");
            } else if(!empty($value)) {
                switch($rule) {
                    case 'min':
                        if(strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} moet minimaal {$rule_value} letters of cijfers zijn.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'max':
                        if(strlen($value) > $rule_value) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} kan maximaal {$rule_value} letters of cijfers zijn.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'matches':
                        if($value != $source[$rule_value]) {
                            $this->addError("{$rule_value} moet hetzelfde zijn als {$item}.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'unique':
                        $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, "=", $value));
                        if($check->count()){ 
                            $this->addError("{$item} bestaat al.");
                        }
                    break;


                }
        }
    }
}

if(empty($this->_errors)) {
    $this->_passed = true;
}

return $this;
}

private function addError($error) {
    $this->_errors[] = $error;
}

public function errors() {
    return $this->_errors;
}

public function passed() {
    return $this->_passed;
}

}
```

register.php:

```
               <?php
                require_once 'core/init.php';

                 if(Input::exists()) {
                 if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

$validate = new Validate();
$validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
    'gebruikersnaam' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 3,
            'max' => 30,
            'unique' => 'groopklanten'
    ),
    'paswoord' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 6,
    ),
    'paswoord_nogmaals' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'matches' => 'paswoord'
    ),
    'bedrijfsnaam' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 3,
            'max' => 30,
    ),
    'kvknr' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 8,
            'max' => 8,
            'unique' => 'groopklanten'
    ),
    'contactpersoon' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 4,
            'max' => 30,
    ),
    'functie' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 4,
            'max' =>30,
    ),
    'telbedrijf' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 10,
            'max' => 12,
            'unique' => 'groopklanten'
    ),
    'adres' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 4,
            'max' => 40,
            'unique' => 'groopklanten'
    ),
    'afleveradres' => array(
            'min' => 4,
            'max' => 40,
    ),
    'postcode' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 6,
            'max' => 7,
    ),
    'woonplaats' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 3,
            'max' => 30,
    ),
    'emailadres' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'min' => 5,
            'max' => 30,
            'unique' => 'groopklanten'
    )
)); 

if($validate->passed()) {
    echo 'geregistreerd';
} else {
    foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
        echo $error, '<br>';
        }
        }
        }
        }

        ?>

        <form action="" method="post">
<div class="field">
    <label for="gebruikersnaam">Gebruikersnaam:</label>
    <input type="text" name="gebruikersnaam" id="gebruikersnaam">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="paswoord">Kies een paswoord:</label>
    <input type="password" name="paswoord" id="paswoord">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="paswoord_nogmaals">Nogmaals uw paswoord:</label>
    <input type="password" name="paswoord_nogmaals" id="paswoord_nogmaals">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="bedrijfsnaam">Bedrijfsnaam:</label>
    <input type="text" name="bedrijfsnaam" id="bedrijfsnaam">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="kvknr">KvK nummer:</label>
    <input type="text" name="kvknr" id="kvknr">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="contactpersoon">Naam contactpersoon:</label>
    <input type="text" name="contactpersoon" id="contactpersoon">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="functie">Functie:</label>
    <input type="text" name="functie" id="functie">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="telbedrijf">Telefoonnummer bedrijf:</label>
    <input type="tell" name="telbedrijf" id="telbedrijf">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="adres">Adres:</label>
    <input type="text" name="adres" id="adres">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="afleveradres"> Afwijkend aflever adres:</label>
    <input type="text" name="afleveradres" id="afleveradres">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="postcode">Postcode:</label>
    <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="woonplaats">Woonplaats:</label>
    <input type="text" name="woonplaats" id="woonplaats">
</div>

<div class="field">
    <label for="emailadres">E-mail adres:</label>
    <input type="email" name="emailadres" id="emailadres">
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate();   ?>">
<input type ="submit" value="Register">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset Velden">

<p> Bij het verzenden gaat u automatisch akoord met de <a href="algemenevoorwaarden.html"> algemene voorwaarden!</a></p>
```

input class:

```
        <?php
        class input {
        public static function exists($type = 'post') {
        switch($type) {
        case 'post':
            return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
        break;
        case 'get':
            return (!empty($_GET)) ? true : false;
        break;
        default:
            return false;
        break;
    }
}

public static function get($item) {
    if(isset($_POST[$item])) {
        return $_POST[$item];
    } else if(isset($_GET[$item])) {
        return $_GET[$item];
    }
    return '';
}
}
```

Database class:

```
       <?php
        class Database {
        private static $_instance = null;
        private $_pdo, 
        $_qeury, 
        $_error = false, 
        $_result, 
        $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host')  . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'),   Config::get('mysql/password'));

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function getInstance() {
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
     self::$_instance = new Database();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
            $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
            $x++;

            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;

        }

    }

    return $this;
}

public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
    if(count($where) === 3) {
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field      = $where[0];
        $operator   = $where[1];
        $value      = $where[2];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} {value} ?";

            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function get($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);

}

public function delete($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('DELETE *', $table, $where);
}

public function insert($table, $fields =array()) {
    if(count($fields)) {
        $keys = array_keys($fields);
        $values = null;
        $x = 1;

        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $values .= '?';
            if ($x < count($fields)) {
                $values .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO groopklanten (`" . implode('`, `', $keys)."`) VALUES ({$values})";

        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
        return false;
}

public function update($table, $id, $fields) {
    $set = '';
    $x = 1; 

    foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
        $set .= "{$name} = ?";  
        if($x < count($fields)) {
            $set .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function results() {
    return $this->_results; 
}

public function first() {
    return $this->_results[0];
}

public function error() {
    return $this->_error;
}

public function count() {
    return $this->_count;
  }
   }
```

init.php

```
         <?php
          session_start();

     $GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'nick16061983',
        'password' => 'N1sn0p1!A',
        'db' => 'websitegroop'
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),  
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'groopklanten',
        'token_name' => 'token'

    )
   );

     spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
     require_once 'classes/' .$class. '.php';
     });
```

All the other things i've tried so far show me that I always can register an existing username, or it will always say it is already registered. When the username is not in my database.

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function count() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\websitegroop\classes\validate.php on line 40 Call Stack

That's because the `action()` method returns `false` instead of current object, which means your query has failed to execute. There are two major reasons for this:

First, look at the following code snippet. There's a small syntax error here,

```
class Database {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo, 
    $_qeury, // syntax error

    ...
```

It should be,

```
class Database {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo, 
    $_query,

    ...
```

Second, your statement `$sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} {value} ?";` inside `action()` method is wrong, it should be like this:

```
$sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
```

So your entire `Database` class should be like this:

```
<?php

    class Database {
        private static $_instance = null;
        private $_pdo, 
        $_query, 
        $_error = false, 
        $_result, 
        $_count = 0;

        private function __construct() {
            try {
                $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host')  . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'),   Config::get('mysql/password'));

            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static function getInstance() {
            if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
             self::$_instance = new Database();
            }
            return self::$_instance;
        }

        public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
            $this->_error = false;
            if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
                $x = 1;
                if(count($params)) {
                    foreach($params as $param) {
                        $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                        $x++;
                    }
                }

                if($this->_query->execute()) {
                    $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
                } else {
                    $this->_error = true;
                }

            }

            return $this;
        }

        public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
            if(count($where) === 3) {
                $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

                $field      = $where[0];
                $operator   = $where[1];
                $value      = $where[2];

                if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                    $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

                    if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                        return $this;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public function get($table, $where) {
            return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);

        }

        public function delete($table, $where) {
            return $this->action('DELETE *', $table, $where);
        }

        public function insert($table, $fields =array()) {
            if(count($fields)) {
                $keys = array_keys($fields);
                $values = null;
                $x = 1;

                foreach($fields as $field) {
                    $values .= '?';
                    if ($x < count($fields)) {
                        $values .= ', ';
                    }
                    $x++;
                }

                $sql = "INSERT INTO groopklanten (`" . implode('`, `', $keys)."`) VALUES ({$values})";

                if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
                return false;
        }

        public function update($table, $id, $fields) {
            $set = '';
            $x = 1; 

            foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
                $set .= "{$name} = ?";  
                if($x < count($fields)) {
                    $set .= ', ';
                }
                $x++;
            }

            $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

            if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public function results() {
            return $this->_results; 
        }

        public function first() {
            return $this->_results[0];
        }

        public function error() {
            return $this->_error;
        }

        public function count() {
            return $this->_count;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: @NickvanHaasteren Glad I could help. Please mark the answer as *accepted* if your issue is resolved. :) [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because the return value of your `action()` method on failure is a **boolean**. So if you attempt to call `count()` on a boolean (which is nonsense, because booleans cannot have methods), it's going to throw that error. Instead, you should check if the return value is even an object first, like so:

```
if ($check) { ... }
```

So long as `$check` is an object, it should pass this if statement. Then you can proceed as normal.

Here is something you can try:

```
// Make sure it's not false
if ($check) {
    // Then count the errors
    if ($check->count()) { ... }
}
```

Random note:

```
if ($check && $check->count()) { ... }
```

This code **could** also work if PHP doesn't check the second argument of the `&&` operator if the first argument equates to false. Just a random note to save lines.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply i tried it but did not work unfortunatly